# not able to ssh to remote machine

Tags: perl

Not able to login to machine... but using the same credential i can log in to the machine

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (host => "9.118.46.36", password=> 'test01', user => 'root', raw_pty => 1, timeout => 20);

    # establishes the ssh connection, 
    # authenticating with that user and password
    $ssh->login();
```

SSHAuthenticationError Login timed out. The input stream currently has the contents bellow: root@9.118.46.36's password:  at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Expect.pm line 828

Comment: is the machine accessible using SSH from shell?

Answer (score 0):

I increased the timeout to 30 and it works...
Is there any way to check what should be the time out.
As system load increase timeout 30 also may not work.

Comment: This is not a good solution to increase timeout. There should be a way which dynamically does this.